# Understanding the names of java Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

I ran this code for my app

```
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> myMap = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
Log.d("threads", myMap.toString());
```

I got the following results

> {Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@e21f0dc, Thread[queued-work-looper,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1fec5e5, Thread[FinalizerWatchdogDaemon,5,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@de438ba, Thread[process reaper,10,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@d51036b, Thread[GoogleApiHandler,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@a4b3ec8, Thread[Thread-2,3,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@5dadb61, Thread[HeapTaskDaemon,5,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7d7a51c, Thread[ReferenceQueueDaemon,5,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@b0d2686, Thread[FinalizerDaemon,5,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7fa6b47, Thread[main,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@2397f74}`

I think the text `Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]` conveys very important information, but I am not quite sure what exactly it means. Could anyone please explain what does it mean?

UPDATE: For another app, I got output `{Thread[Thread-7,5,main] = ..` so `Thread-7` seems to indicate something different from `pool-1-thread-1`, so I want to understand what the names of threads indicate?

Comment: Well `Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]` is the output of `Thread.toString()` and if you have a look at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#toString()) (and the sources confirm this and the order mentioned)  you'll see that you get: name, priority and group name. In your case all threads except "process reaper" have priority 5 and you basically have 2 groups: "main" and "system".

Comment: @Thomas thanks it was very helpful! so name of first thread is  `pool-1-thread-1` but it  should be indicating something else as well on running the code on different app i get `{Thread[Thread-7,5,main]=[Ljava...` so i understands name is `Thread-7` priority is 5 but still it indicate something different from `pool-1-thread-1` .

Comment: Well `pool-1-thread-1` basically is just a name and you could provide any name you want, e.g. `new Thread("very_important_looking_but_meaningless_name")`. The information you get from the name _can_ have a meaning but doesn't have to. In your particular case I _assume_ there's a bunch of thread pools and that thread is the first one of pool 1 (whatever that pool is used for).

Comment: @Thomas I think `{Thread[Thread-7,5,main]` indicates that the application has already started 6 threads and now the 7th thread is running and for `pool-1-thread-1` only one thread was created and being reused again and again (which is better I think), but not sure why the `pool` is mentioned only for  `pool-1-thread-1` and not for `Thread-7` but as you commented I also think that is not very important, thx for your help!!!

Comment: Yeah, the important thing here is "I think": those names may or may not provide helpful information and without knowing who created the thread to see how the names are constructed it's more of a guess. `Thread-7` could mean there are already 6 other threads running but those could be dead already, there could be more threads etc. Also the `pool` might bear some meaning as opposed to `Thread-x`, i.e. the `pool-...` one is likely part of a thread pool while other might be "standalone" but again, that's not a sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Thread names indicate whatever the person who wrote the code that created the thread decided. There is no simple answer to that question.

However, some names seem self-explanatory, e.g. the names listed in the formatted output below. Names like:

- `main` - The main thread
- `Finalizer` - The thread responsible for executing `finalize()` methods.
- . . .

Other names are documented. E.g. the javadoc of [`new Thread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread--) says:

> Allocates a new `Thread` object. This constructor has the same effect as `Thread (null, null, gname)`, where `gname` is a newly generated name. Automatically generated names are of the form **`"Thread-"+n`**, where `n` is an integer.

So `Thread-7` would appear to be the thread created by the 8th call to `new Thread(...)` that didn't specify a name.

A thread name like `pool-1-thread-1` would then also be an auto-generate name, for Thread #1 in Thread Pool #1.

---

To print the result of calling [`Thread.getAllStackTraces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces--) in an easily readable format, use code like this:

```java
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> myMap = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
for (Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    for (StackTraceElement elem : entry.getValue())
        System.out.println("    " + elem);
}
```

*Example Output (Java 8)*

```
Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)
Thread[main,5,main]
    java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method)
    java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1610)
    Test8.main(Test8.java:7)
```

*Example Output (Java 15)*

```
Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:176)
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:170)
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
Thread[Notification Thread,9,system]
Thread[Common-Cleaner,8,InnocuousThreadGroup]
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    java.base@15.0.1/jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(CleanerImpl.java:148)
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    java.base@15.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:134)
Thread[main,5,main]
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method)
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1649)
    app//Test.main(Test.java:9)
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Native Method)
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:241)
    java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:213)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, yes that is a great way to print the output in a more readable form but I wanted to understand what thread names indicate, sorry I was unclear with my question, I have updated it now, thx!

Comment: @beginner Thread names indicate whatever the person who wrote the code that created the thread decided. There is no simple answer to that question.

Comment: You are right, I guess it was a stupid question, thx for your help:)